SSIS using parameter in "Lookup transformation" for the table to use in "Connection"
I have a set of ETL that use "Lookup" steps that connect to an excel file, the sheet of this file is set as the "table" to connect (see attach).
enter image description here
now I need to use different set of values depending on an input parameter, so I would like to create many sheets in my excel files with the different data to lookup, and I would like also to use an input parameter to connect to the right sheet (the same parameter value is used across the etl in other steps).
following the example attached: if I need to run the ETL for "MPDE" parameter I would like that the lookup step sets the value in "Use a Table or a view" option (or in "Use results of an SQL query") to "MPDE" in order to fetch the data in that sheet.
thanks in advance
I tried inserting parameter in "advance editor" but the query returns error
enter image description here

If I understand what you are trying to do you can create a variable to hold the SQL query you want.  Then another variable to hold the Excel Sheet name.  Then use an Expression to build out the SQL query using the Excel Sheet Name variable, and then in your data flow task use Variable as Source and select the SQL variable that uses the expression.
